# Ios Swift (UITableView with several level)

Tags: swift

I am new developer in Swift.
I did a single ViewController, with UITableView inside --> list management.
User can add/modify information in the list.
Seems to be OK.
 --> Information are stored in DB (CoreData : entity/attributes)

example : 
table 1 : 
Entity = type of food

Attributes = name : string

Question : 
**I don't know how to create a view were I can have 2 levels of TableView.**

Example :

table 1 :

Entity = type of food

Attributes = name : string
example : vegetables, meat, fruit, ...

in the view, user can add a new kind of food himself (example fish)

table 2 :

Entity = Aliment

Attributes = name : string

example : beef <-- (meat), banana <-- (fruit) etc ...).

but **linked with table 1** (***beef is meat and not fruit***)

how to manage this kind of list in an UIview :
create/modify/delete/display a type of food and add some "aliment" in it ?

like a two level list and list2 is linked with the list 1 ?
Any example in swift ?

Comment: I think you'll want to create a 2nd table view that you access by selecting a row in the first table view. I'm a little unclear on your question though.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually simple, you just have to create a new instance of tableview and add it as a subview of your cell in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.
Example :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let tableview = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width, 50)
    cell.addSubview(tableview)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks thibaut, do you mean it is like a tableView inside each cell of my first list ? do you have a concrete example or sample / do you know an apps where I can see it ?

Comment: Yes that's what i mean and no i don't have any concrete sample of this.
What you can do to manage this is create a UITableViewController for each cell and add the view of the controller as a subview, this way you can subclass UITableViewController thus instantiating your subclass.
Combining this with a switch statement you can have a different tableview controller for each cell.

Comment: The real question here is do you actually need it, if you want two levels of tableview you already have sections + cells